# C fgets and sscanf in loop : prevent useless looping

Tags: c, fgets, scanf

I have a problem with looping and `fgets` and `sscanf` to get the input.

I know to problem is from the size of the malloc with the input. If the user enter number larger than the malloc i want to ask again to enter a new number.
But in this code, if an user enter a too large number, it's looping lot of time (size of the word / 8) i think.

How to ask again to the user to enter new number without looping 4 times for example.
See the example i made with big number.

The idea was to free the input after the loop but it's doesn't works. Any ideas ?

There is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(void) {
    char x[8];
    char y[8];
    int result = 0;
    char *input=malloc(sizeof(char)*8);
    bool answer = 0;
    char *pos;

    while(!answer) {

        fgets(input, sizeof(input)-1, stdin);
        //remove the /n from fgets
        if ((pos=strchr(input, '\n')) != NULL)
            *pos = '\0';

        result = sscanf (input, "%s %s", x, y);
        printf("%d\n", result);
        if(result < 2) {
            fprintf(stderr, "There is an error with the number you give, try again\n");
        } else {
            printf("%s\n", x);
            printf("%s\n", y);
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

And the output for : "01 01"

```
01 01
2
01
01
```

Output for : 000000005 000000005

```
0000000000005 000000000000005
1
There is an error with the number you give, try again
1
There is an error with the number you give, try again
2
5
0000
1
There is an error with the number you give, try again
1
There is an error with the number you give, try again
```

Comment: `sizeof(input)` is the size of the pointer, not of the malloc'd memory. You are lucky, that the chances are good that both are 8.

Comment: Assuming you fix your `input` buffer to dynamic grow for consuming your line content, you realize you ave a whole new problem trying to `sscanf` a string like `"0000000000005"` into a `char[8]`, right? I mean, you're trying to shove 14 chars into a buffer that only holds 8, and `sscanf` as you're using it is blissfully unaware of this limitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fgets() doesn't throw away the rest of the line when it's longer than its buffer. You have to do it yourself.

If you look at this code I frequently use with `fgets`, you'll see the two tasks separated, and in which circumstances which one is done:

```
/*Returns 0 if OK, a negative value if EOF.*/
int fpurge(FILE *f)
{
    int c;
    while((c=fgetc(f))!=EOF && c!='\n')
    { }
    return (c==EOF ? -1 : 0);
}

/* Returns a nonzero value if found, zero if not. */
int truncate_newline(char *str)
{
    int bRet=0;
    if(str!=NULL)
    {
        char *pNewLine = strchr(str, '\n');
        if(pNewLine!=NULL)
        {
            bRet = 1;
            *pNewLine = '\0';
        }
    }
    return bRet;
}

/* Returns 0 if buffer is full, a positive value if line is complete,
   a negative value if EOF (implies buffer full). */
int fclean(char *str, FILE *f)
{
    int ret = 1;
    if(!truncate_newline(str))
        ret = fpurge(f);
    return ret;
}
```

You can see that your own code does the `truncate_newline` part, but not the "throw away the rest of the line" (here in the function `fpurge`) part.

If you change your code thusly, it should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 8

int main(void) {
    char x[BUFFER_SIZE];
    char y[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int result = 0;
    char *input=calloc(BUFFER_SIZE, sizeof(char));
    bool answer = 0;
    char *pos;

    while(!answer) {

        fgets(input, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin);
        //remove the /n from fgets
        if ((pos=strchr(input, '\n')) != NULL)
            *pos = '\0';
        else
        {
            int c;
            while((c=getchar())!='\n' && c!=EOF) {}
        }

        result = sscanf (input, "%s %s", x, y);
        printf("%d\n", result);
        if(result < 2) {
            fprintf(stderr, "There is an error with the number you give, try again\n");
        } else {
            printf("%s\n", x);
            printf("%s\n", y);
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Or simply replace the whole if() with `fclean(input, stdin);`

Comment: Thx for the explanation ! also in your code, replace `char *pNewline = strchr(str, '\n');` by `char *pNewLine = strchr(str, '\n');`

Comment: @martialdidit **PS**: fgets() already includes the null terminator in its size parameter, you don't need to substract 1 yourself.

Comment: Not checking the return value from `fgets()` is a problem.  Should `fgets()` return `NULL`, the state of `input` is not well defined.

Comment: @chux Yeah, I outright replaced the magic size with a `#define`, less problems that way. And zero-initialized the buffer to reduce the "fgets fails" problem, though I can't be arsed to actually solve it by checking its return value.

Comment: With a rare read error, "... the array contents are indeterminate and a null pointer is returned.".  C11 §7.21.7.2 Checking the `fgets()` result is the only remaining defined result.

Comment: I feel the least tiring way to do so will be passing fgets()'s return value to fclean() as a third parameter.